# What are these artifacts on my model's surface? How do I remove them?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I'm importing some models from Blender to Unity, and I came to notice that on the surface of the model, strange geometrical artefacts appear. These are not visible in the original blender model. What are these, and how do I remove them?

Thanks!

**Blender:**
[image]
**Unity:**
[image]

Comment: Disable shadows on the light or the material.

Comment: @iggy ok I turned shadows from the light and it fixed the issue, though I'm wondering if I turn off shadows isn't this going to affect the shadow generation in my scene?

Comment: There is [blender.stackexchange.com](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) for all your Blender questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok figured it out!

In order to remove similar artifacts you need to do the following:

1. Select the light source and then changed the Bias from "Use Pipeline settings" to "Custom"

[image]

2. Increase the Depth from 0.48 to 2 and voila!

[image]

Artifacts are gone!